# Какую книгу посоветуете?

Tags: c++, c, linux, книги

Я изучаю Си и заодно Си++

Одну какую-то книжку прочел, так что ознакомлен с основами.

Меня сейчас интересуют операции с файлами, с ОС.

На компьютере установлен Linux Ubuntu, хотелось бы также научиться делать в нем графическое оформление программ, пишу я в gEdit, не использую никоких средств разработки, компилю по-простому, в терминале, через g++.

Какую книгу посоветуете? Чтобы мне ее пойти и купить в магазине, электронную не надо.

Comment: Вам может быть интересен ответ на вопрос - http://hashcode.ru/questions/515/

Answer (score 5):

Для написания пользовательских интерфейсов могу посоветовать прочитать 
Жасмин Бланшет - Qt 4. Программирование GUI на С++.
Но для этого уже нужно хорошо разбираться в С++, советую
Харви Дейтель, Пол Дейтель. Как программировать на С++

По поводу Си сам изучал по книге
Как программировать на Си за 21 день ( название дурацкое, но книга очень даже хороша )
Для системного программирования подойдут две книги Роберта Лава
Системное программирование в Linux,
Разработка ядра Linux.

Одной книгой здесь не обойтись =(

**UPD**

- [Жасмин Бланшет, Марк Саммерфилд Qt 4. Программирование GUI на C++](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4005805/)
- [Роберт Лав Разработка ядра Linux](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2918313/)
- [Роберт Лав. Linux. Системное программирование (уже нет в озоне)](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3961491/)
- [Харви Дейтель, Пол Дейтель. Как программировать на С++](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4369460/)

Comment: спасибо, у меня только вопрос - эти книги можно пойти и в книжном купить? Есть какие нибуть шансы найти их в магазине?

и нельзя ли поподробнее про книги Роберта лава?

Comment: Всё это легко достать. Я обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Кроме Qt есть еще GTK+.

- [Основы GTK+: Часть 1. Зачем использовать GTK+?](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/os-gtk1/index.html)
- [Основы GTK+, Часть 2: Как использовать GTK+](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/os-gtk2/index.html)
- [Основы GTK+, Часть 3: Развертывание приложения GTK+](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/os-gtk3/index.html)

Печатных книг ни разу не видел.

Comment: И в убунте тоже?

Comment: GNOME сделан с использованием GTK+. Так что и в убунте.

Comment: По Gtk+ есть печатные книги - http://www.amazon.com/Gnome-Gtk-Programming-Bible-Wiley/dp/0764546406, правда на английском.

Answer (score 1):

Последнее, что я читал в бумажном виде по C в Linux, - это книга "Программирование в Linux" Н.Н Иванова. Про графику там ничего не было. А про базовые вещи было расписано довольно понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Для GUI приложений могу посоветовать [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) и неплохой [туториал](http://www.qteverywhere.com/qt/book/c-gui-programming-with-qt-4-2ndedition.pdf) к нему, правда на английском и в электронном виде, но, думаю, оно того стоит. Насчет файлов, по-моему проще man читать. Насчет тредов(операции с ОС - это о чем было)) есть хорошая бумажная книжка по примитивам синхронизации: [Анатомия параллелизма](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2512096/)

Comment: спасибо, хороший материал, правда все-таки желательно на русском

Comment: вот на русском: http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=690884
здесь первая книжка - это перевод старой верии туториала.
Остальные скорее всего барахло. Честно, ни одной вменяемой книжки на русском не видел по qt.

Comment: еще вопросик есть - откуда подгрузить эту библиотеку?

Comment: Вообще у Вас в дистрибутиве убунты она должна быть. Поставьте все девелоперские пакеты для qt4.

Comment: Да, что-то типа того. Я убунтой почти не пользовался. По идее сначала надо найти все пакеты qt4, потом делать apt-get.

Answer (score 1):

Хорошая книга Н. Метью, Р. Стоунс "Основы программирования в Linux". Там есть обо всем понемногу, но вполне достаточно, чтобы писать довольно серьезные программы. Также даются начальные сведения по программированию в Gtk+ и Qt.

По GTK+, насколько мне известно, нет хороших книг на русском. По английски рекомендую 
Krause A. Foundations of GTK Development. Хотя она уже немного устарела.